# Allowing an RSS feed to show "Complete action using..." in Android

Tags: android, html, xml, rss

I am trying to make a subscribe page on our podcast and I really like the way one site laid theres out:

http://onepiecepodcast.com/subscribe/

On their site, you can click "BeyondPod" and in Android you will get the dialog box asking if you want to complete the action using the browser (raw XML) or an app you have installed (BeyondPod). The funny thing is they are using the same anchor in all three so I am thinking the device handles it differently and it is more of an illusion.

The problem is, I cannot replicate that on my site. On my site it just brings you to the raw XML feed and never gives you the pop up suggestion. I do not think they are doing anything special, in the onclick they are just sending google analytics. Is there a special way to allow this popup. What makes the pop up work on their site but not mine?

Answer (score 0):

I think they might be using app links, you should check the documentation http://applinks.org/ basically you will be doing something like this in your website:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="yourdomain://rss" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="yourid" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Your app" />
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="yourdomain://rss" />
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Your App" />
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.yourdomain" />
    <meta property="al:web:url"
          content="http://yourdomain.com/rss" />
</head>
<body>
Hello, world
</body>
</html>
```

and manage that in your app, you have to insert this in manifest:

```
<activity android:name="YourActivityTitle"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="http"
android:host="yourdomain.com" />
<data android:scheme="https"
android:host="yourdomain.com" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```